# AngularJS form data to Ruby on Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, api

I created a simple API with Ruby on Rails,and I'm trying to send data from a form with AngularJS. The thing is that the App is sending the post method and the backend is creating the new records, so far it's working, but it creates it with Null values.

This is the form:

```
<div ng-controller="postController">
    <form name="messageForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control" ng-model="message.content">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is the Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('postController', function($scope, $http) {
  // create a blank object to handle form data.
    $scope.message = {};
  // calling our submit function.
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/messages',
      data    : $scope.message, //forms user object
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
     })
      .success(function(data) {
        if (data.errors) {
          // Showing errors.
          $scope.errorContent = data.errors.errorContent;
        } else {
          $scope.message = data.message;
        }
      });
    };
});
```

And in the RoR's API Controller, this is the Create method:

```
def create 
    respond_with Message.create(params[:message])
end
```

The only rows are:

- ID which is generated automatically.
- And 'content'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign a key to your `message` object in `data` parameter, like this:

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/messages',
  data    : { data: $scope.message },
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
 })
 .sucess(function(data){ ... });
```

And then, in your controller:

```
def create 
  respond_with Message.create(params[:data])
end
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: (Part 1) Thank you for replaying! This helped, but now I'm getting this in the console: 

_"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/messages. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:59076' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."_

Comment: (Part 2)
But I have this method in my Application Controller:

_before_filter :add_allow_credentials_headers
    def add_allow_credentials_headers
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = request.headers['Origin'] || '*'
        response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    end_

Comment: @GabrielAlejandro If you still getting that error, open it in a new question to get more attention!